DocuSign Envelope with multiple documents with different Signatories
We have a requirement where we have to send multiple documents for signatures.
For Example:Document 1 has to signed by only Signatory 1, Document 2
has to be signed by only Signatory 2, Document 3 has to be signed by
only Signatory 3.

Can we use a single envelope containing all the documents? Also, can all signatories see all documents during signing or can we ensure that Signatory see only those documents where his/her signature us required?
Thanks!!

You can do this using document visibility.
That feature enables you to specific which recipient sees which document.
You can find a code example showcasing how to do this here - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-document-visibility/
Here is the C# code:
private static EnvelopeDefinition PrepareEnvelope(
    string signer1Email,
    string signer1Name,
    string signer2Email,
    string signer2Name,
    string ccEmail,
    string ccName,
    string docPdf,
    string docDocx,
    string docHtml)
{
    EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
    {
        EmailSubject = "Please sign this document set",
        Documents = PrepareDocumentsForTemplate(
            signer1Email,
            signer1Name,
            ccEmail,
            ccName,
            docPdf,
            docDocx,
            docHtml),
        EnforceSignerVisibility = "true",
    };

    Signer signer1 = PrepareSigner(
        signer1Email,
        signer1Name,
        "1",
        "1",
        new List<string> { "2", "3" },
        "**signature_1**",
        "pixels",
        "20",
        "10");
    Signer signer2 = PrepareSigner(
        signer2Email,
        signer2Name,
        "2",
        "1",
        new List<string> { "1" },
        "/sn1/",
        "pixels",
        "20",
        "10");

    CarbonCopy carbonCopy = new CarbonCopy
    {
        Email = ccEmail,
        Name = ccName,
        RecipientId = "3",
        RoutingOrder = "2",
    };

    envelopeDefinition.Recipients = new Recipients
    {
        CarbonCopies = new List<CarbonCopy> { carbonCopy },
        Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1, signer2, },
    };

    envelopeDefinition.Status = "sent";

    return envelopeDefinition;
}

private static Signer PrepareSigner(
    string signerEmail,
    string signerName,
    string recipientId,
    string routingOrder,
    List<string> excludedDocuments,
    string tabsAnchorString,
    string tabsAnchorUnits,
    string tabsAnchorXOffset,
    string tabsAnchorYOffset)
{
    return new Signer
    {
        Email = signerEmail,
        Name = signerName,
        RecipientId = recipientId,
        RoutingOrder = routingOrder,
        ExcludedDocuments = excludedDocuments,
        Tabs = new Tabs
        {
            SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>
            {
                new SignHere
                {
                    AnchorString = tabsAnchorString,
                    AnchorUnits = tabsAnchorUnits,
                    AnchorXOffset = tabsAnchorXOffset,
                    AnchorYOffset = tabsAnchorYOffset,
                },
            },
        },
    };
}

private static List<Document> PrepareDocumentsForTemplate(
    string signer1Email,
    string signer1Name,
    string ccEmail,
    string ccName,
    string docPdf,
    string docDocx,
    string docHtml)
{
    byte[] pdfFileContentInBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(docPdf);
    byte[] docxFileContentInBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(docDocx);

    string htmlFileContentsString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(docHtml);
    htmlFileContentsString = htmlFileContentsString.Replace("{USER_EMAIL}", signer1Email);
    htmlFileContentsString = htmlFileContentsString.Replace("{USER_FULLNAME}", signer1Name);
    htmlFileContentsString = htmlFileContentsString.Replace("{CC_EMAIL}", ccEmail);
    htmlFileContentsString = htmlFileContentsString.Replace("{CC_NAME}", ccName);
    byte[] htlmFileContentInBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlFileContentsString);

    return new List<Document>
    {
        new Document
        {
            DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(htlmFileContentInBytes),
            Name = "Order acknowledgement",
            FileExtension = "html",
            DocumentId = "1",
        },
        new Document
        {
            DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(docxFileContentInBytes),
            Name = "Battle Plan",
            FileExtension = "docx",
            DocumentId = "2",
        },
        new Document
        {
            DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfFileContentInBytes),
            Name = "Lorem Ipsum",
            FileExtension = "pdf",
            DocumentId = "3",
        },
    };
}

